# Find an integer $m$ such that for an endomorphism of the n-dimensional torus there is a rational number with period $m$

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Show that if $T_A : \mathbb{T}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{T}^n$ is an endomorphism of the torus and $x \in \mathbb{Q}^n \backslash \mathbb{Z}^n$, then there exists an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such $T_A^m (x)$ is periodic for $T_A$. The matrix $A$ that induced $T_A$ has entries in $\mathbb{Z}$.

This is a question posed in a book about Dynamical Systems Theory. And I know how to solve the problem for the case in which $T_A$ is and automorphism, but in this case this is all I have:

If there exists an $m$-periodic $x$, then $x$ is also $mk$-periodic, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies the two following equations:

$[A^m x] = [x] \Leftrightarrow A^m x - x = p_1 \in \mathbb{Z}^n$

$[A^{mk} x] = [x] \Leftrightarrow A^{mk} x - x = p_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^n$

Subtracting the first equation to the second yields:

$A^{mk} x - A^m x = (A^{mk} - A^m)x = p_2 - p_1 = p \in \mathbb{Z}^n$

But how can I find $m$ such that the result above is true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding ultimately periodic point of linear transformation of the torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676510/finding-ultimately-periodic-point-of-linear-transformation-of-the-torus)

Comment: Why the exact duplicate?